# Let other dev push in a branch I created

Tags: git, gitlab, versioning

I just create a branch in gitlab. I can push in that branch without problem but the other devs can't push in that branch (it's rejected).

I'm not the one who created the project (I can't push to master), I just created a branch.

Is it possible to autorize every dev to push in a certain branch ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you add them to the project?

Comment: Yep, I did add them to the project.

Comment: I don'know much about gitlab but pretty sure with default settings it allows pushing to other's branches. usually when push is rejected it should print explanation to stdout. What do your coworkers see?

Comment: They're pushing with phpstorm so the only message they see is "Push rejected".

Comment: I didnt understood the question. Are you both trying to push the same branch to master? would you paste the push rejected error log that will say what is happening. First of all, all the users need to added to the project. Say you have project `banana` all the users , 1,2,3 needs to be added to the project and all of them needs to have ssh keys added in their gitlab ssh-key fingerprint.

Comment: Aren't you pushing from a fork? If so, you'll need to add the other devs as members of your project. Multiple people can push to the same branch, as long as they're members of that project.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab has a concept of `protected branches` that only users with the role `Masters`or above can push to. By default `master` branch is protected. You can change this setting by clicking on the `cog` icon -> Protected branches on the project page.

Answering your question, the branch that you have created might be a protected branch (maybe there is a regex match that makes it protected) or others may not have at least `Developer` role access to it.

> Is it possible to authorize every dev to push in a certain branch?

Yes. Configure it under settings(`cog` icon) -> Members